Cardinality of a multirange? How many ranges or gaps are there in a multirange?
How do I obtain the cardinality of a multirange?
I'm using range_agg() to aggregate ranges, which merges ranges if they are continuous, or returns what looks like an array of ranges if the ranges are discontinuous.
I want to detect if there are any gaps in the multirange and wanted to use cardinality() for this. A cardinality of 1 would mean no gaps, a cardinality of 2 means 1 gap, etc.
However cardinality is not defined on a multirange, because a multirange is not technically an array:
with x(a) as (
  values
    (daterange(date '2024-01-30', date '2024-03-31', '[)')),
    (daterange(date '2024-04-01', date '2024-04-30', '[)'))
)
select cardinality(range_agg(a)) from x;

returns
ERROR:  function cardinality(datemultirange) does not exist
LINE 6: select cardinality(range_agg(a)) from x;

I can probably implement the function myself with unnest() and counting the number of resulting rows, but I'm curious if there are any other good solutions.

A multirange is distinct from an array. The former is a pretty recent addition, and far less commonly used. So fewer convenience features ...
I don't think an equivalent of cardinality() for arrays is implemented for multiranges. (Pretty sure, actually.)
But a variant of unnest() is implemented, you can use that in a subquery expression:
(SELECT count(*) FROM unnest(my_multirange))

Or roll your own custom function (like you already pondered):
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cardinality(anymultirange)
  RETURNS int
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE AS
'SELECT count(*)::int FROM unnest($1)';

The polymorphic type anymultirange comes in handy to make it work smoothly with function type resolution.
count() returns bigint, but I think integer is reasonable. (There won't be more than 2^31 distinct ranges.)
Applied to your example:
SELECT id, range_agg(a) AS my_multirange
     , (SELECT count(*) FROM unnest(range_agg(a))) AS dist_ranges1
     , cardinality(range_agg(a)) AS dist_ranges2  -- custom func
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY id
ORDER  BY id;

Works in pg 15, too:
fiddle

I wrote an almost identical function. Why did you use text as the return type though?

@Colin'tHart: That was an oversight. Fixed, now. count() returns bigint, but I think integer is reasonable.

Yes, the supplied cardinality(anyarray) also returns integer.
